# Keras model evaluation accuracy on training data set is lower than fitting accuracy

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I get some strange result on evaluating my model with the training data set.
I want to develop a cnn with such structure:

```
Input --> conv1d --> MaxPool1D --> Flatten --> Dense --> Dense
```

This is my model:

```
model = Model(inputs=[inputLayerU, inputLayerM], outputs=outputLayer)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])    
model.fit([inputU, inputM],outputY , epochs=100, steps_per_epoch=500)
```

and this is the result of training the model:

```
Epoch 95/100
500/500 [==============================] - 329s 659ms/step - loss: 0.5058 - acc: 0.8845
Epoch 96/100
500/500 [==============================] - 329s 659ms/step - loss: 0.4137 - acc: 0.9259
Epoch 97/100
500/500 [==============================] - 329s 659ms/step - loss: 0.3221 - acc: 0.9534
Epoch 98/100
500/500 [==============================] - 329s 659ms/step - loss: 0.2938 - acc: 0.9596
Epoch 99/100
500/500 [==============================] - 330s 659ms/step - loss: 0.4707 - acc: 0.9352
Epoch 100/100
500/500 [==============================] - 329s 659ms/step - loss: 0.4324 - acc: 0.9543
```

I save the model and weights and then load them and evaluate the model using the same training data set:

```
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("GCN-conv1d-acc.h5")
loaded_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])
score = loaded_model.evaluate(inputTrain,outTrain,steps=500, verbose=0)
```

However I get this result:

```
[7.320816993713379, 0.3042338788509369]
```

I expected to get some results close to the fitting result but it's too far away.
I checked these postes:

[Strange behaviour of the loss function in keras model, with pretrained convolutional base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123198/strange-behaviour-of-the-loss-function-in-keras-model-with-pretrained-convoluti/51124511#51124511)

http://blog.datumbox.com/the-batch-normalization-layer-of-keras-is-broken/

They say Keras has some problems with batch normalization and dropout layers, however I don't use neither of them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, Adam is the the variation of SGD, which does not take into account the entire data points for model fitting, and pick a batch(subset of rows) for the training,

So this could lead to inconsistency, when you first train model and save weights, 
The next time you run the algo using same weights, the subset on which the weights are being applied could have changed

Comment: So which optimizer I should use for fitting and evaluation to get the same result?

Comment: In model.fit use batch_size argument to explicitly set the number of rows to consider in a batch, It should be equal to number of rows in your dataset, however if your dataset is large(rows) , it may take longer than usual to train the model,

Comment: For more info onsetting the batch size, consider referring the following link https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221886/how-to-set-mini-batch-size-in-sgd-in-keras

Comment: thanks but I can't use batch_size, it throws an error: "If your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, you should specify the `steps_per_epoch` argument (instead of the `batch_size` argument, because symbolic tensors are expected to produce batches of input data)."