# Keras BatchNorm Layer giving weird results during training and inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I am having an issue with Keras where evaluate function gives different training loss (way higher) and accuracy(way lower) value as compared to the value that I get during training. I am aware that this question has already been asked at several places ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123198/strange-behaviour-of-the-loss-function-in-keras-model-with-pretrained-convoluti/51124511#51124511), [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6977)), but I think my issue is different and still not answered in those forums.

### **Explanation of the Task**

It is supposed to be a very simple task. All I am doing is to overfit to my own dataset of 256 images (29x29x3) with 256 output classes (one for each image).

## Dataset

**Case 1**
**x_train** = All the pixel values in the image = i where i goes from 0 to 255.
**y_train** = i

**Case 2**
**x_train** = Centre 5*5 patch of the pixel values in the image = i where i goes from 0 to 255. All the other pixel values are same for all the images.
**y_train** = i

This gives me 256 images in total for the training data in each case. (It would be more clear if you just have a look at the code)

**Here is my code to reproduce the issue -**

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os

import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler, Callback
from keras import backend as K
from keras.regularizers import l2

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL.Image
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import clear_output

# The GPU id to use, usually either "0" or "1"
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"

# To suppress the warnings
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

## Hyperparamters
batch_size = 256
num_classes = 256
l2_reg=0.0
epochs = 500


## input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 29, 29

## Train Image (I took a random image from ImageNet)
train_img_name = 'n01871265_279.JPEG'
ret = PIL.Image.open(train_img_name) #Opening the image
ret = ret.resize((img_rows, img_cols)) #Resizing the image
img = np.asarray(ret, dtype=np.uint8).astype(np.float32) #Converting it to numpy array
print(img.shape) # (29, 29, 3)

## Creating the training data
#############################
x_train = np.zeros((256, img_rows, img_cols, 3))
y_train = np.zeros((256,), dtype=int)
for i in range(len(y_train)):
    temp_img = np.copy(img)
    ## Case1 of dataset
    # temp_img[:, :, :] = i # changing all the pixel values
    ## Case2 of dataset
    temp_img[12:16, 12:16, :] = i # changing the centre block of 5*5 pixels
    x_train[i, :, :, :] = temp_img
    y_train[i] = i
##############################

## Common stuff in Keras
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    print('Channels First')
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 3, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (3, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    print('Channels Last')
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 3)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 3)

## Normalizing the pixel values
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')

## convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)

## Model definition
def model_toy(mom):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add( Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(7, 7), strides=(1,1), input_shape=input_shape, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg)) )
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom, epsilon=0.00001))
    #Default parameters kept same as PyTorch
    #Meaning of PyTorch momentum is different from Keras momentum.
    # PyTorch mom = 0.1 is same as Keras mom = 0.9

    model.add( Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(7, 7), strides=(1, 1), kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom, epsilon=0.00001))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom, epsilon=0.00001))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom, epsilon=0.00001))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=1024, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom, epsilon=0.00001))

    model.add( Conv2D( filters=2048, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg) ) )
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom, epsilon=0.00001))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=4096, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom, epsilon=0.00001))


    # Passing it to a dense layer
    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(1024, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=mom, epsilon=0.00001))

    # Output Layer
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg)))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    return model

mom = 0.9 #0
model = model_toy(mom)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
              #optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0, nesterov=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    shuffle=True,
                   )

print('Training results')
print('-------------------------------------------')
score = model.evaluate(x_train, y_train, verbose=1)
print('Training loss:', score[0])
print('Training accuracy:', score[1])
print('-------------------------------------------')
```

***Small Note*** - I was able to successfully do this task in PyTorch. It is just that my actual task requires me to have a Keras model. That's why I have changed the default values of the ***BatchNorm layer (the root cause of the issue)*** according to the ones I used to train PyTorch model.

Here is the image that I used in my code. 
[image]

Here are the results of training.
[Case1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r2sQx44TnCpdCnS_hodRLNLyJjaed6AO/view?usp=sharing) of the dataset
[Case2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iigiaiPcSYTsOQGMa9oL09OaO6cvfu3h/view?usp=sharing) of the dataset

If you look at these two files, you would be able to notice the discrepancies in the training loss during training vs inference.
***(I have set my batch size to be equal to the size of my training data so as to avoid some the reasons BatchNorm generally creates problems as mentioned [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6977))***

Next, I looked at the source code of the Keras to see if there is any way I can make the BatchNorm layer use the batch statistics instead of the running mean and variance.
[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/moving_averages.py) is the update formula that Keras (backend - TF) uses to update the running mean and variance.

```
#running_stat -= (1 - momentum) * (running_stat - batch_stat)
```

So if I set the momentum value to be 0, it would mean that the value assigned to the runing_stat would always be equal to batch_stat during the training phase. Thus, the value it will use during inference mode will also be same (close) as batch/dataset statistics.
Here are the results for this little experiment with the same issue still occurring.
[Case1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17zN4E4PFPRGK_wpUDgpZ-zRYPJCpwXeR/view?usp=sharing) of the dataset
[Case2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TDd9vIyDn_QooDDOs_jJMI-canfxBvb4/view?usp=sharing) of the dataset

Programming Environment - Python-3.5.2, tensorflow-1.10.0, keras-2.2.4

I tried the same thing with tensorflow-1.12.0, keras-2.2.2 as well but it still did not solve the issue.